# Get posts with tag all post types

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, tags

I'm trying to get all posts that have a specific tag, regardless of what type of post that is. I've tried every solution I've found (here on SO and further), but nothing works: I always only get the normal 'post' type from my wp_query.

I've tried this:

```
$query_args = array(
        'tag' => $tag,
        'post_type' => array('post', 'praktijk', 'expert', 'download', 'product', 'event')
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

And I would think that would work. Replacing the array of post_types with the string 'any' also doesn't work.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Code and syntax appear correct. Do you actually have CPTs tagged with `$tag`?

Comment: Hm. I re-created all tags and now it seems to work.. Still don't know why..

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
$query_args = array(
    'tag' => $tag,
    'post_type' => 'any',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Please have a look here: [Tag Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) and [Type Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters).